# not able to update or install any package on Ubuntu 16

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I am unable to install **phpmyadmin** on my **ubuntu 16.04.3 VPS**, I was getting error while installation.

please check below mentioned error details

root@fmk-me1-1:/home/flashmarket# apt-get install phpmyadmin

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

phpmyadmin : Depends: php but it is not installable

```
          Depends: php-mbstring but it is not installable
          Depends: php-xml but it is not installable
          Depends: libjs-sphinxdoc (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
          Depends: dbconfig-mysql but it is not installable or
                   dbconfig-no-thanks but it is not installable or
                   dbconfig-common (< 2.0.0) but it is not installable
          Depends: php-php-gettext but it is not installable or
                   php-gettext (<= 1:7.0) but it is not installable
          Recommends: php-curl but it is not installable
          Recommends: php-gd but it is not installable
          Recommends: php-bz2 but it is not installable
          Recommends: php-zip but it is not installable
          Recommends: php-tcpdf but it is not installable
```

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: when I was trying to update getting error.

root@fmk-me1-1:/home/flashmarket# apt-get update

Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_nijel_phpmyadmin_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

Answer (score 0):

1. Execute sudo *apt-get autoremove*
2. Then execute *sudo apt-get update*
3. Then try to install the package what you want

Comment: I have done autoremove but still same


root@fmk-me1-1:/home/flashmarket# sudo apt-get update
0% [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net (91.189.95.83)]
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_nijel_phpmyadmin_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)